# How to have early bound attribute names as string constants?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

**Context**

I am using crmsvcutil to generate early bind entities. I am also utilizing entity name string constants `MyEntity.EntityLogicalName` for example in statements like the following (using alternate key):

```
 var reference = new EntityReference(MyEntity.EntityLogicalName, "my_attribute_name", myValue)
```

**Question**

*I would like to eliminate the "my_attribute_name" string literal in the statement. How can I do this?*

Unfortunatelly  I can not find it in the generated C# model.

Missed I something? If not, maybe there is an extension to crmsvcutil (similarly to the optionset generator sameple?

Comment: For primary keys I was using entityInstance.ToEntityReference(), but there isn't any overloads for Alternate Keys afaik.... Maybe worth adding a custom extension method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, you can use the C# 6 `nameof()` expression to get the name of the property. If you convert the name to lower case, you end up with the logical name:

```
var logicalName = nameof(MyEntity.MyAttributeValue).ToLower();
```

With that being said, I rarely find myself having to do something like this. Often you can use [`Entity.ToEntityReference()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.toentityreference.aspx) for a more strongly typed approach.

Additionally the constructor you use for `EntityReference` is only meant to be used for alternate keys (otherwise one would just use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326140.aspx) that takes a `string` and a `Guid`)

Comment: Thanks, sounds cool. However security permissions apply (CRM online, sandbox plugin) so my question is: is reflection involved, or this is a compile time thing?

Comment: Yes, nameof is evaluated at compile-time. There should thus be no issues using it in a sandboxed plugin (but I still recommend that you consider if the alternative solutions are relevant for you)

Comment: Many thanks. Although I did not stressed: I have reasons to use alternate keys, Also, getting attribute names as string are task to solve in other situations too (as original question title says) so alternate keys is just a sample context, not the problem itself to solve.